# Jquery total noob import inquiry relating to where to put files

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I downloaded the Jquery Raty plugin: https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty

Then I installed this folder structure into my {{static_url}}js folder and named it Raty.

Then I imported it into my template as follows and put the path as the location of where its images are stored.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/raty/js/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.thingrating').each(function(index){
          $(this).raty({
            readOnly:  false,
            path: "{{ STATIC_URL }}js/raty/img/",
            start: $(this).children("span:first").text(),
            click: function(score, evt) {
                var vote_url = "rate/" + this.attr('id').substring(2) + "/" + score + "/";
                $.ajax({
                  url: vote_url,
                  success: function(){
                    alert('vote successful');
                  }
                });
            }
          });
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Is this correct? I'm not seeing that it is working in my template, so want to make sure this process of storing the script and importing it into my template is correct before I continue to decipher what is wrong...

Here's the rest of my template:

```
{% block body %}
    <h2>Things</h2>
        <div class="block" id="block-tables">
          <div class="content">
            <p></p>
            <div class="inner">
                <table class="table">
                  <tr>
                    <th class="first">Name</th>
                    <th class="last">Rating</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td>{{ item.modelname }}</td>
                    <td><div class="thingrating" id="t_{{ item.id }}"><span style="display:none;">{{ score }}</span></div></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="actions-bar wat-cf">       
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You also need to include jQuery file because raty.js is dependent on  it ??

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Are you getting any JavaScript error? Are you sure the selector is matching? Can you post the rest of your template?

Comment: I don't get it exactly... what do you mean?

Comment: @PaoloMoretti no, no error, but it's not showing stars as it should

Comment: it does not show stars at all or simply does not show correct initial value?

Comment: @FAngel It doesn't show anything at all where the score should be, nor does it show stars.

Comment: `$(document).ready` - is it executed? I'm not familiar with django. Is your template provided a django template or some JS template? (processed on a server or on a client?)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qp69H/1/) demo. It works fine (well, except that looks like `start` should be changed to `score` as I understand that way you want to define initial score). Incorrect path to images will not break it at all. Browser will simply show default icon for not available image if path to images is wrong. Not sure what is in `{{static_url}}` variable. If it contains something like 'http://example.com/static' - you must add a slash after it.

Possible problems - script tag for raty appears before jQuery. Or results of template processing are not available on page when `$(document).ready` event happens.

Comment: Thanks... out of curiosity, how did you load the raty script in the jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Take a look at left panel. There is a button "Manage Resources". There you can attach external scripts/styles

Comment: I double checked my paths and they look fine. Totally stuck no this... The script order didn't change things either. Even tried changing the image paths to the one in the jsfiddle demo and no luck :( What would cause a the results of template processing to not be available on the page when `$(document).ready` happens?

Comment: Press Ctrl+U (view source) and search for "thingrating" there. It will show sources without any AJAX calls. If there is no any items with class "thingrating", than it is loaded with AJAX or template is javascript template and processed on client, not on server (in this case it will happen in some other document ready which is started after document ready you posted here).

Comment: This is the only `thingrating` showing up: `<td><div class="thingrating" id="t_2"><span style="display:none;">2</span></div></td>`

Comment: Is your document ready executed at all? try to add alert into your handler and see if it will pop out. Or use a debugger (F12 in any browser, for FF you may need to install firebug extention)

Comment: Yeah it's not executing at all. Why would that be? I put an alert in my base.html which this template extends and that executes fine...

Comment: The only idea I have is not available jquery. Try to do something like `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/raty/js/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>` and see if it will show alert. If it will - than you must move your jquery tag higher (put it before raty)

Comment: It's weird because I'm running the same code on two different pages... on one it works, and on the other it doesn't and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Try to add additional jquyer and see if it works. There could be a lot of different issues why it wokrs on one page and does not work on another one: different script order, not attached script, something that breaks exection of scritps...

Comment: Nope :( A bit stumped... Is there anyway I can send you more info offline?

Comment: if you have it online - you can give a link to it here

Comment: ok let me push my code and will do that... you mean the site, right?

Comment: And which page I should look at?

Comment: On that page - there is no raty at all. No raty script, no document.ready. Nothing

Comment: Possibly you have two similar or equal templates and you updated only one of them.

Comment: I updated that one for sure. The original file looked radically different so I'm positive. Even on my local machine I don't see raty. But I see other changes I make to the template.

Comment: What would cause it to not show up? It seems really strange. I'm positive the script is on the page I'm modifying and viewing.

Comment: I'm going to delete this question I think and create a new one based on this particular problem.